# Remove tooltip at out of hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image where I put some coords and display a tooltip like this:

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseover", updateTooltip)
}

function updateTooltip() {
  tooltip.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-text');
  var coordinates = this.getAttribute('coords').split(',')
  tooltip.style.left = coordinates[0] + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1] + 'px';
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">

        <area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">
        
         <area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">
         
         <area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">
         
         <area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
      <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>   
</map>

</div>
```

Problem is I want to remove tooltip when mouse come over tooltip or coords. Because if we hover USA, we can't hover México because tooltip don´t allow it.

How can I achieve it? Regards

Comment: You probably want to use two separate handlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of the finer grained `mouseover` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mouseeneter` & `mouseleave` event and create another function which will trigger on `mouseleave`.Inside this function set `display:none` to the tooltip and on mouse enter set it to `display:block`

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", updateTooltip);
  areas[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", removeTooltip)
}

function updateTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "block"
  tooltip.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-text');
  var coordinates = this.getAttribute('coords').split(',')
  tooltip.style.left = coordinates[0] + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1] + 'px';
}

function removeTooltip() {
  tooltip.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

area {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="mapImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y7HuHDQ.png" usemap="#image-map">

  <map name="image-map">

            <area target="" data-text="USA Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173" alt="USA" title="USA" href="" coords="110,140,182,141,186,148,198,146,198,140,214,139,224,134,234,143,221,150,213,154,205,156,205,170,199,174,194,181,193,188,162,182,158,171,149,173,145,179,141,170,124,168,121,173,112,168,105,158" shape="poly">
            
             <area target="" data-text="Mexico Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="MEXICO" title="MEXICO" href="" coords="124,172,137,171,141,178,152,173,160,181,162,204,179,199,179,211,157,212,173,216,146,204,136,196,125,188" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Japan Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="JAPAN" title="JAPAN" href="" coords="705,106,716,106,721,146,687,184,667,175" shape="poly">
             
             <area target="" data-text="Germany Shops: Manchester,TN - Num: 6621418372 WIXOM ,MI - Num:662728173"  alt="GERMANY" title="GERMANY" href="" coords="418,111,436,108,433,124,418,124" shape="poly">
          <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>   
    </map>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice try. Mexico and USA flicks a lot.

Comment: @statosdotcom may be because of mouse movement

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but it could mean "nice solution - bad UX". I am only pointing this because I have found the same solutions of yours, but your answer came first here. I applause you, but this behavior, for a while, is quite unexpected. Thank you. Excuse me, please.

Comment: Is not possible to fix flicks?

Comment: @Pedro, excuse me, I think, anyway, the original question was correctly answered by **brk**. If this flicks or not, that's another question. You wanted to remove tooltips, **brk** showed a way to do it. If not a better answer arises, this should be marked as the correct one. Thank you.